# python numpy polyfit function

Tags: python, numpy

I'm new to python and haven't found an answer on this site so far.

I'm using numpy.polyfit in a loop and getting an error as below and don't understand as when I run the code in debug everything works fine and the len of arrays going into the function are the same:

> Error Runtime exception: TypeError: expected x and y to have same length

My code is below:

```
    import numpy as np
    from collections import defaultdict 
    bb = [ 10, 11, 12, 22, 10, 11, 12, 11, 10, 11, 12, 22, 10, 11, 12, 11, 10, 11, 12, 22, 10, 11, 12, 11, 10, 11, 12, 22, 10, 11, 12, 11, 10 ]
    i = 0   
    b = -3
    bb_gradient = defaultdict(dict)
    while ( b <= 0 ):
        print i
        print len(range(3))
        print len(bb[b-3:b])
        bb_gradient[i][0], _ = np.polyfit( range(3), weekly_bb_lower[b-3:b], 1 )
        i += 1
        b += 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: What is `weekly_bb_lower` in this case? Can't run your program without it.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming `bb` is `weekly_bb_lower`. Change `while ( b <= 0 )` to `while ( b < 0 )`. because when `b` becomes 0, `weekly_bb_lower[-3:0]` will return an empty list. a `list[-n:0]` is supposed to be empty.

Comment: Ah! Forgot to change that variable!! Sorry about that. Otherwise, thanks and I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: No, list[-n:0] is not supposed to be empty

Comment: Using a negative index in python like `list[-n]` is just short form for `list[len(list)-n]`. Now try figuring out what `bb[-3:0]` would mean in your case.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid referencing an empty list by moving the last three elements to the start of your list:

```
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict 
bb = [ 10, 11, 12, 22, 10, 11, 12, 11, 10, 11, 12, 22, 10, 11, 12, 11, 10, 11, 12, 22, 10, 11, 12, 11, 10, 11, 12, 22, 10, 11, 12, 11, 10 ]
bb = bb[-3:] + bb[:-3] # moves the last three elements of the list to the start prior to looping
bb_gradient = defaultdict(dict)
for i in range(3):
    bb_gradient[i][0], _ = np.polyfit( range(3) , bb[i:i+3], 1 )
```

Prashanth's explanation is correct.